# How to fill a textbox based on its previous textbox value using ajax

Tags: php, ajax, onblur

i have a from like this

```html
<div class="row1">
  <input type="text" class="pinCode" name="pin[]" value="">
  <input type="text" class="areaName" name="location[]" value="">
</div>
<div class="row1">
  <input type="text" class="pinCode" name="pin[]" value="">
  <input type="text" class="areaName" name="location[]" value="">
</div>
<div class="row1">
  <input type="text" class="pinCode" name="pin[]" value="">
  <input type="text" class="areaName" name="location[]" value="">
</div>
```

I have a table in database named "city" with two column "pincode" and "cityname".
As I am filling the pinCode textbox ,I want to populate CityName textbox with city's name respective to input pincode.
please suggest some Jquery or ajax codes and php success page as i am a beginer.

Comment: You need to call ajax based on `pincode` and get the value of `cityname` in response and fill it to the textbox.

Comment: other than showing html show us what exactly have you tried to solve problem ?

Comment: so we should write everything for you?

Comment: I would look over the jQuery developer pages. Has lots of examples.

Answer (score 0):

on mouse out of pincode, you can call an ajax function like this,

```
 $(document).on("mouseOut or onBlur",".pincode",function() {
    var pincode = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
         url: "ajax.php",
         type: "POST",
         dataType: "HTML",
         async: false,
         data: {"pincode": pincode},
         success: function(data) {
               // data will have the area name echo'ed in ajax.php file
               $(this).closest('areaName').val(data);

      }
  });
});
```

ajax.php

```
your code to get the area name based on pincode

echo $areaname;
```